# No space left on device error when installing anaconda on Ubuntu on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, disk-usage, oracle

I created an Ubuntu virtual machine using Oracle VM VirtualBox and I assigned 110GB of disk space and 6500MB of RAM to it. When installing anaconda I am getting this error while unpacking payload:

> Failed to write all bytes for base_library.zip
> fwrite: No space left on device
> [2277] INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory!

This is a brand new ubuntu installation and I haven't added any files.

My `du` command shows:

> 8724 .

at the end.

Comment: what does your df command say? Here is a link to a similar problem. There is an answer that worked 2/3 down the page. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3262